# Object / Vector (no generics) to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, vector, byte

Say I have `Point p` (custom type) which holds two ints **x** and **y** and I want to convert this point to byte array so when I read it, the byte array will hold 8 bytes (2 integers) can I do something like `p.toString().getBytes()`? Also same questions go for vector I have a vector that holds points can I use `vector.toString().getBytes()` or it won't work like I expect it to?

Comment: for points, it probably won't work like you expect, it depends on what Point.toString() does.  for vector it won't work.

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: Start by calling toString() on your Point. What does it return? Why do you think changing this string to bytes using the getBytes() method would lead to exactly eight bytes? String is documented: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29. You want to use a DataOutputStream and write the two integers to this stream.

Comment: You cannot, eg, "alias" a Java object with an array and get a byte view of the object -- it simply does not work that way.  You can use shift/mask operations to move the data from your two ints into a byte array, but that's predicated on you understanding what I mean by "shift/mask operations".